# Formtastic form not submitting - rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

I'm trying to create a very simple submitting form inside _form.html.erb file. However, the form is not submitting. If I try to create a new post, after I click submit button, the page just refreshes and nothing has been saved to database. I'm using Rails 6.0.2.1.

This is the form under _form.html.erb

```
<form>
  <%= semantic_form_for @post do |f| %>
    <div class="form-row">
      <%= f.inputs do %>
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
          <%= f.input :title, :label => 'Title', :required => true, :wrapper_html => { :class => "important", :size => 10 } %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
          <%= f.input :body, :label => 'Post', :required => true, :input_html => { :class => 'autogrow', :rows => 10, :cols => 20, :maxlength => 500  } %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
          <%= f.input :section, :label => 'Tag', :as => :select, :collection => ["Finance", "Arts/Music", "Sports", "Mood", "Technology", "Health", "News", "Politics", "Literature", "Food", "Life", "Pet", "Shopping"] %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
          <%= f.input :location, :as => :country, :label => 'Where are you posting' %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
          <%= f.input :username %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <%= f.actions do %>
      <%= f.action :submit, label: "Submit" %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</form>
```

Part of posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create
    "puts creating post"
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :section, :location, :username)
  end
end
```

models/post.rb

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
    attr_accessor :title, :body, :section, :location, :username
end
```

Comment: Can you verify that it is hitting the `create` method? For example if you put in `puts "got here!"` does that get logged out in the log or terminal?

Comment: @RockwellRice It doesn't hit the create method as nothing is printed out in the terminal.

Comment: You did update the code from what you have so something would actually print out though, right?  If so,  when you inspect the form what route and method does it have in the HTML?